# How to get one result using wpdb class?

Tags: query, wpdb

```
function asec_get_link_color() {
        global $wpdp;
    $query = "SELECT value FROM wp_theme_options WHERE property = 'link-color'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

It doesn't return any value.

Comment: `global $wpdp` won't get you very far.

Answer (score 2):

You've made no attempt to check for errors, e.g. $result may be false, also your code would fail if there was more than one result returned.

So instead of using a custom table, and reinventing the wheel, use the provided APIs:

`get_theme_mod` and `set_theme_mod`

So your code now becomes:

```
function asec_get_link_color( $default_color='blue') {
    return get_theme_mod( 'link-color', $default_color );
}
```

Using set_theme_mod also handles all your SQL escaping and security code for you.

Also keep in mind that you use wp_theme_options as your table name, but you're not the only person building themes. At the very least, add an identifier unique to your theme and yourself.